# How to make the turtle draw one step at a time

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

I have a hangman game, im suppose to draw one part of the hangman every wrong letter, but I do not know how to draw one step of the turtle at a time

That's what I have:

```
def drawsturtle(userInput,word):
```

then the steps I have to make:

```
import turtle
hangman = turtle.Turtle()
hangman.circle(45)
hangman.right(90)
hangman.forward(150)
....
```

How can I write the code so that every userInput not in word one of those steps gets drawn?
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined a count variable to track the number of incorrect guesses, you could define a function to draw out the required parts. In the example below I assumed 3 incorrect guesses. I've added a 3 second pause so you can see the output.

```
import turtle, time

hangman = turtle.Turtle()

def draw_hangman(count):
    if count >= 1:
        hangman.circle(45)
    if count >= 2:   
        hangman.right(90)
    if count == 3:
        hangman.forward(150)
    time.sleep(3)

draw_hangman(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have code to detect that an incorrect letter has been guessed, you can call the `turtle.write` method to write out the incorrect letter.

Refer to the method signature below:

```
 turtle.write(arg, move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))
    Parameters: 

        arg – object to be written to the TurtleScreen
        move – True/False
        align – one of the strings “left”, “center” or right”
        font – a triple (fontname, fontsize, fonttype)

    Write text - the string representation of arg - at the current turtle position according to align (“left”, “center” or right”) and with the given font. If move is true, the pen is moved to the bottom-right corner of the text. By default, move is False.
```

For more details:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/turtle.html

Comment: I want to draw a part of a hangman everytime it guesses a wrong letter, I got when he guesses the wrong letter but cant get the turtle to draw only one part like the head or a arm...